# Adding more ram to computer, what kind can I buy

Tags: memory, motherboard

So I've been looking to add more ram to my PC (I have 2 empty slots), and I just want to make sure I don't buy something I can't use, but at the same time want to get a good deal if possible.

I read a resource which told me to get an identical stick of what my computer is currently using, and I could do that, but I wonder what exactly constitutes "identical".  For instance, I realize since my motherboard takes DDR3 ram, I will need DDR3 ram, but what about mixing manufacturers?

Currently I have RAM from ADATA, PC3-12800 (800MHZ) is the max bandwidth.  Do the sticks I buy have to be PC3-12800 (800MHZ) as well?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your motherboard manual, or post your motherboard here and we can help find that information, since you might have a limit on the amount of RAM, maximum speed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the make and model of your PC to see what RAM to use. Some computers require you to provide (2) identical chips and not all speeds are able to be used in on all MOBO's. Look here at http://www.crucial.com go to the drop down and choose your PC's make and model. They will give you a list of compatible chips to use. You will definitely need to use PC3 (DDR3) RAM but speed and if you need a matching pair or not is the real question. What MOBO do you have or what model tower?

Answer (score 0):

Something important to watch for that you may not know about is ecc/buffered RAM and non ecc/unbuffered RAM. Your motherboard will either support one or the other, not both. Most boards use unbuffered but you might want to check your board or see which your current RAM is. Besides what you already listed, this is the only real "show stopper" I can think of. It would definitely be best though to look up your motherboard and see the specs it lists for ram: max GB, max speed, nonecc or ecc, etc.

I've never had issues mix and matching ram brands, but manufactures recommend against it. Most recommend buying ram in a set when replacing them as they are factory "matched" when in a set.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether your motherboard supports [multi-channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture) operation of RAM (most motherboards do). If it does support, you can buy another RAM module with exact same specification as the current one. Which will improve the performance due to multi-channel operation.

If your motherboard doesn't support it, you can buy RAM with different speed (but the same CAS, timing, voltage etc...). In this case, effective speed at which they will operate is "lowest speed among all the RAM modules installed".

**Note**: If you are planning to re-use an existing spare module, make sure on the above points and also check you motherboard's manual to see what would work and what wouldn't. If you are out shopping to buy a new pair of RAM modules, buying the exact same module is advisable.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the RAM type is the same (DDR3) you can mix and match. It won't damage anything but if you have lets say 2 2GB chips and one is 1600mhzz and another is 1333mhz the higher speed ram will automatically run at the lower clock speed.

So, performance wise it's not the best thing to do, but you can do it and there shouldn't be anything that breaks. You'll likely experience a noticeable improvement in performance regardless.